# Как при создание элемента присвоить ему выполнение функций с параметрами при клике

Tags: javascript

Всем привет,
Хочу создать игру, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, при создание игрового поля мне нужно что-бы при клике на клетке вызывалась функция с параметрами. Клетки создаются и вызывают фукцию при клике, но вот как передать параметры я хз :(

Вот что я имею на данный момент :

```
function createGameArea(row, col, elem) {
    let createGameArea = document.createElement('div');
    createGameArea.className = 'game-area';
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      let createRow = document.createElement('div');
      createRow.className = 'game-row';
      for (let j = 0; j < row; j++) {
        let createCell = document.createElement('div');
        createCell.className = 'game-cell';
        createCell.addEventListener('click', checkThis); //Вот тут
        createRow.appendChild(createCell);
      }
      createGameArea.appendChild(createRow);
    }
    elem.appendChild(createGameArea);
  }

  function checkThis(param) {
    console.log(param);
  }
```

Comment: У вас тут немного опечатка j < row, а не col. Если используете динамическую генерацию клеток можете также попробовать делегировать клик на елементе с класом "game-area". Если кратко: слушаем клик по елементу "game-area" и проверяем клас event.target.classList содержит ли он клас клетки, если так, то передаем параметры в функцию проверки)))

Comment: @GGO спасибо, я даже не заметил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
createCell.addEventListener('click', () => {
    checkThis(СЮДА ПАРАМЕТРЫ);    
});
```

Comment: спасибо большое ^-^